# After installation JSS 11.0.0 onto Sitecore 9.1, URL is not giving right response

Tags: jss

I've installed JSS 11.0.0 onto Sitecore 9.1.

**URL:**https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/110/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services_1100.aspx

[image]

I have added API key as mentioned here: https://medium.com/infocentric/how-to-setup-javascript-services-jss-for-sitecore-9-7e54893c64d8 .

[image]

Now i want to verify my installation, but when i am running URL getting below response:

[image]

Please suggest, what i am missing?

How to verify JSS 11.0.0 installation onto sitecore 9.1?

**log:**

> WARN  [Sitecore Services]: API key {A81EE064-F9A1-4719-A7A1-279C8B20CAFB} is not found.

Comment: In which database is the API key? The blog is for Sitecore 9, the API key must be in the master database. See the documentation https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install

Comment: @Jan, I added in master DB. It seems need to publish this item so it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is bit small but i want to specified so no one else again face this issue. After setup API key to `master` DB, **publish** this item.

Now when i am running URL it's giving response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Sitecore 9.1 you should not create the API key in Core DB [I mean the link you referred above is for previous version of Sitecore], You have to create the API key in master DB under the path **/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/API Keys**

If you don't have the site setup then look at your default site in Sitecore.config, if the database is "web" then you need to publish the API key to work.

```
<site name="website" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web"../>
```

If you already have the app setup, Check your  entry in JSS application config located in "\Website\App_Config\Include\yourappname.config", if the database is "web" then you need to publish the API key. If it is "master" you actually no need to publish and it will read the content from master context.

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            inherits="website"
            name="portal-poc-app"
            hostName="hostname"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/appname"
            startItem="/home"
            database="web" />
```

Comment: i created key on master DB only. i missed publish this item. ;(

Comment: okay.. it actually works based on the context DB, so the context DB in your case might be web.

Comment: Yes Gobinath. Anyway issue is fix. Happy learning.